# some errors about this package node-icu-charset-detector

Tags: node.js, heroku

anyone knows how to solve this problem

while trying to build the solution on heroku .. it makes some errors about this package node-icu-charset-detector

I tried to install this package but - it always gives me these errors on [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qzsC.png)

Comment: Did you read the error message, and what it suggests that you should do to fix the issue?

Comment: @robertklep , here's all the logs on heroku dashboard : https://pastebin.com/Lnvi5QMK

Comment: the error message :        ../node-icu-charset-detector.cpp:7:28: fatal error: unicode/ucsdet.h: No such file or directory
       #include <unicode/ucsdet.h>

Comment: Did you also read [the installation instructions](https://github.com/mooz/node-icu-charset-detector#installation)? Specifically the part about `libicu` being a requirement.

Comment: I did not find a guide for windows , anyway I'm trying to install the icu from their website : http://icu-project.org/download/4.0.html

Comment: no installation files , I still can't handle this issue -_-

Comment: You are mixing environments and errors: the Windows error that you are showing points towards the Windows SDK not being installed, the Linux error (on Heroku) points towards `libicu` not being installed.